# What's is wrong with this query? Left Join and Self Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this problem with left join and self join and I don't know how to resolve if anyone can help.

I have two tables :

TABLE str_markers_example { id int PK,  display_value varchar, short_code varchar }
TABLE str_results_example { id int PK, dna_result_id int, str_marker_id int, allele_1, allele_2 }

When I run this query I get 12 records :

```
SELECT
str_results_example.str_marker_id,
str_results_example.allele_1 AS progeny_a1, str_results_example.allele_2 AS progeny_a2
from str_results_example join str_markers_example on str_results_example.str_marker_id = str_markers_example.id
where str_results_example.dna_result_id = 85281
```

But when I try to get the same number of records using a self join with a left join I only get 9 records :

```
SELECT
str_results_example.str_marker_id,
str_results_example.allele_1 AS progeny_a1, str_results_example.allele_2 AS progeny_a2,
dam_results.allele_1 AS dam_a1, dam_results.allele_1 AS dam_a2
from str_results_example
left join str_markers_example on str_results_example.str_marker_id = str_markers_example.id
left join str_results_example as dam_results on str_results_example.str_marker_id = dam_results.str_marker_id 
where str_results_example.dna_result_id = 85281 
and dam_results.dna_result_id = 30308
```

I tried left join but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

SQL Dump for both tables :

```
CREATE TABLE str_results_example (
  id int NOT NULL,
  dna_result_id int NOT NULL,
  str_marker_id int NOT NULL,
  allele_1 int,
  allele_2 int
)
;

INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140125, 85281, 1, 209, 219);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140126, 85281, 2, 150, 158);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140127, 85281, 3, 117, 121);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140128, 85281, 4, 127, 133);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140129, 85281, 5, 178, 182);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140130, 85281, 6, 248, 254);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140131, 85281, 7, 151, 161);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140132, 85281, 8, 81, 89);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140133, 85281, 9, 115, 117);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140134, 85281, 10, 206, 206);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140135, 85281, 13, 162, 168);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (140136, 85281, 16, 266, 270);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8152, 30308, 3, 121, 125);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (7964, 30308, 1, 209, 221);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8365, 30308, 10, 206, 206);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8372, 30308, 13, 160, 162);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8397, 30308, 16, 266, 266);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8282, 30308, 8, 81, 97);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8244, 30308, 7, 151, 151);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8335, 30308, 9, 117, 119);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8156, 30308, 5, 178, 182);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (8163, 30308, 6, 248, 248);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (5722, 3657, 1, 209, 219);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (5980, 3657, 4, 125, 127);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (5931, 3657, 3, 103, 117);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (5834, 3657, 2, 150, 158);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6147, 3657, 6, 248, 254);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6238, 3657, 8, 77, 89);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6266, 3657, 11, 141, 145);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (5989, 3657, 5, 178, 182);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6194, 3657, 7, 151, 161);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6335, 3657, 12, 141, 151);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6404, 3657, 13, 166, 168);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6243, 3657, 9, 115, 117);
INSERT INTO str_results_example VALUES (6253, 3657, 10, 206, 214);


CREATE TABLE str_markers_example (
  id int NOT NULL,
  display_value varchar(255),
  short_code varchar(255)
)
;

INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (1, 'ETH10', 'eth_10');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (2, 'ETH225', 'eth_225');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (3, 'ETH3', 'eth_3');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (4, 'BM2113', 'bm_2113');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (5, 'BM1824', 'bm_1824');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (6, 'SPS115', 'sps_115');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (7, 'TGLA122', 'tgla_122');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (8, 'TGLA227', 'tgla_227');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (9, 'TGLA126', 'tgla_126');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (11, 'MGTG4B', 'mgtg_4b');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (13, 'TGLA53', 'tgla_53');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (14, 'TGLA57', 'tgla_57');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (15, 'TGLA48', 'tgla_48');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (16, 'BM1818', 'bm_1818');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (10, 'INRA23', 'inra_23');
INSERT INTO str_markers_example VALUES (12, 'SPS113', 'sps_113');
```

What I am trying to do is make a query where I keep all the data (markers) from the first dna_results_id and get all the matching from the second dna_result_id

So the table would be something like this :

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJOL7.png)

Comment: Please add sample input and output data.  By the way, the second query is using an alias `dam_results`, which never seems to be defined anywhere.

Comment: dam_results is being define in the left join ( left join str_results_example as dam_results  ). 
I think the problem from what I have been talking is that the dna_results_id are not null and since they have ids it is like a normal join. I just wish to know how to keep all the records from the first dna_results_id = 85281

Answer (score 0):

In the second query you add a condition on dam_results.dna_result_id in the where clause. At that time your join on dma_results becomes a normal join and is not considered as a left join any more . You have to put your condition in the left join, then you will have your 12 rows.

```
SELECT
str_results_example.str_marker_id,
str_results_example.allele_1 AS progeny_a1, str_results_example.allele_2 AS progeny_a2,
dam_results.allele_1 AS dam_a1, dam_results.allele_1 AS dam_a2
from str_results_example
left join str_markers_example on str_results_example.str_marker_id = str_markers_example.id
left join str_results_example as dam_results on str_results_example.str_marker_id = dam_results.str_marker_id and dam_results.dna_result_id = 30308
where str_results_example.dna_result_id = 85281
```